# Selenium Firefox then Chrome and IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Is it possible to run my Selenium test on Firefox and then the same test on Chrome and IE? How can I do this?

Comment: specify the selenium version, language and its version (like java, python) and browser versions for specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java, you can handle automatically the required binaries (*chromedriver*, *geckodriver*, and *IEDriverServer.exe*) by means of [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager).

Take a look a complete example as a parameterized JUnit test case. Notice that the test code is single, and in the test parameters (method `data()`) you chose the browsers you want to run your code (Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MultipleBrowsersTest {

  protected WebDriver driver;

  @Parameter
  public Class<? extends WebDriver> driverClass;

  @Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
  public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { ChromeDriver.class }, { FirefoxDriver.class },
        { InternetExplorerDriver.class } });
  }

  @Before
  public void setupTest() throws Exception {
    WebDriverManager.getInstance(driverClass).setup();
    driver = driverClass.newInstance();
  }

  @After
  public void teardown() {
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.quit();
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // Your test code here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WebDriver is an interface where FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver,  InternetExplorerDriver are implemented on**. These browser specific drivers implement all the methods that are defined in WebDriver interface. As a user, you are only using the methods of WebDriver (by calling them with WebDriver object) and has been hidden by how each driver has implemented those methods. so, you no need to worry about each implementation of the method.

But the only thing you have to specify is as follows:

to run tests on Firefox browser:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

to run tests on Firefox browser:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

to run tests on Internet browser:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

similarly, for almost all browsers we have corresponding Driver classes available.

Along with language WebDriver libraries, you need to download .exe files for each browser.

```
geckodriver.exe - firefox 48.0 and above (before 48 version, firefox has built-in support and no need of geckodriver.exe
chromedriver.exe - all chrome versions
InternetExplorerDriver.exe - all IE versions
```

and once you download them, you make the selenium aware of where these executable are kept in:

```
 System.setProperty("browser_key", "/path/to/the/driver")
 example:
 System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","G:\\Selenium\\Firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe"); // to set path to firefox driver, similary for chrome and IE browser. 
remember key changes based on the browser.
```

Or alternatively, you can keep the .exe in PATH environment variables (in Windows) or similar functionality in other OSs.

**Once you get the driver instance, you can use all the methods that are available on WebDriver interface.** `(these are browser independent)`

for example:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com") // to lauch browser and visit google page

WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.id("SearchInput")) // to find an element in a page. returns a WebElement object.
searchField.sendKeys("search something") // to enter text into input field.
```

References:

1. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html
2. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nodeJS and the way I did it through a foreach.

```
const browsers = ['ie','firefox','chrome'];
browsers.forEach(function(item, index){
    Tests(item,i);
});
function Tests(item, index) {
    describe("This is a test", function() {});

}
```

Then I placed item where the browser name should be in your code